# how to insert sqlite table date field value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

i have create table like below and inserting the value using insert query from ruby on rails but it's not updating the date value with table. Rest of the field values updating correctly....

give me

**Table structure:**

```
CREATE TABLE [Approval] (
[InstallationName] TEXT  NULL PRIMARY KEY,
[Approver] TEXT  NULL,
[ApprovalCRCdate] DATE  NULL,
[ApprovalTime] TIME  NULL,
[ApprovalCRC] NUMERIC  NULL,
[ApprovalStatus] TEXT  NULL
)
```

**insert query:**

```
insert into [Approval] values('_EGONSEOSX0043','dfgdfg','6/6/2011' ,'16:13:14' ,324234 ,'Approved')
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe you should change the field's type to TEXT?
SQlite's DATE datatype has numeric affinity and you are using `/` that is not a number.

But I think it should all get inserted since SQLite has 'dynamic typing'